# Moving Canvas by Mouse

Tags: java, swt

I want to move my button to anywhere in my Frame by drag and drop. I can't do it in SWT. Can anybody help me ? I have tried many times and I don't found any listener about it.

Answer (score 0):

For those JComponents that do not support Drag-and-Drop by default, or JComponents you wish to customize their Drag-and-Drop behaviors, you need to pass them a new TransferHandler. The easiest way to create a TransferHandler is to instantiate one and pass it a beans property, or the name of a get/set method in the class (ie., text and icon are beans properties for JButton). We also need a MouseListener to export the drag.

```
JButton button = new JButton("This is the text");
TransferHandler transfer = new TransferHandler("text");

//the JButton can now be dragged and the text will be dropped
button.setTransferHandler(transfer);

button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
         JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
         TransferHandler handle = button.getTransferHandler();
         handle.exportAsDrag(button, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Question is for SWT, not Swing.